# ¿Como hacer un map en mi array de objetos para sumar los totales en Angular?

Tags: angular

Mi servicio devuelve un array de objeto con estas propiedaedes:

```js
operations = [
    {
        amount: 1500;
        type: 'ingreso';
    },
    {
        amount: 1500;
        type: 'ingreso';
    },
    {
        amount: 1000;
        type: 'egreso';
    },
    {
        amount: 9500;
        type: 'egreso';
    },
]
```

lo que quiero hacer es: hacer un **map** en el **array operations** y sumar los **amount** por **type** de operacion y guardar el resultado en las variables **incomeAmount y amountEgreso**.

hice esto:

```js
operations: Operation[] = [];
incomeAmount;
amountEgreso;

constructor(public operationService: OperationService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAmountByIncom();
  }

  getAmountByIncom(){
    this.operationService.getOperations().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.operations = res;
        this.incomeAmount = this.operations.map(item => item.amount).reduce((count, item) => count + item, 0)
      },
      err => console.error('Error al obtener operaciones de tipo ingreso')
    )
  }
```

**En el html:** quiero mostrar por ejemplo la variable **incomeAmount** con el resultado:

```html
 <p>{{incomeAmount}}</p>
```

pero no me suma los amount, muestra esto: 01500150080000700007000055000280005000180065000

Answer (score 1):

Por un lado parece que el array de objetos está mal construido, pero lo mismo es error tipográfico (los puntos y comas al final de cada propiedad deberían ser sólo comas).

Por otro lado, tiene pinta de que estás tratando la propiedad amount como string y por lo tanto la función reduce te concatena cada "amount". Puedes tratar de cambiar el casting de la propiedad o simplemente esquivarlo con un `parseFloat` o `parseInt` según corresponda:

```
this.operations.map(item => item.amount).reduce((count, item) => count + parseFloat(item), 0)
```